# JS How to create a function that count the number of hashtags

Tags: javascript, loops, count, numbers

I am new to coding and have been given this question to answer.

This question is;

Create a function that receives a string that will contain a number of mentions and hashtags as on Twitter.

```
   E.g. "So excited to start  @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp"
```

The function should return an object describing the number of hashtags and mentions found:

```
   { hashtags: 2, mentions: 1 }
```

The code that I have created is this;

```
function countHashtagsAndMentions(str) {
   let split = str.split(" ");
    let count = 0
    for (let i = 9; i < str.length; i++) {
        let hash = split.filter(hashtag => hashtag.match(/#/g))
        if (hash === 1) {
          count ++
         }
        let total = {
        hash = count,
      }
    return hash
   }
 }
```

My code is being run against this;

```
describe("countHashtagsAndMentions", () => {
  it("returns an object", () => {
    expect(typeof countHashtagsAndMentions("")).to.equal("object");
  });
  it("returns {hashtags: 0, mentions: 0} if it finds none", () => {
    expect(
      countHashtagsAndMentions(
        "hello this is a tweet guaranteed to get very little engagement"
      )
    ).to.eql({ hashtags: 0, mentions: 0 });
  });
  it("recognises no mentions", () => {
    expect(countHashtagsAndMentions("#yolo")).to.eql({
      hashtags: 1,
      mentions: 0
    });
  });
  it("recognises no hashtags", () => {
    expect(countHashtagsAndMentions("@yobo")).to.eql({
      hashtags: 0,
      mentions: 1
    });
  });
  it("finds multiple hashtags and mentions and returns that number", () => {
    expect(countHashtagsAndMentions("#yolo @bolo #golo")).to.eql({
      hashtags: 2,
      mentions: 1
    });
    expect(countHashtagsAndMentions("@boyo #goyo @loyo #zoyo")).to.eql({
      hashtags: 2,
      mentions: 2
    });
    expect(
      countHashtagsAndMentions(
        '"So excited to start at @northcoders on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp"'
      )
    ).to.eql({ hashtags: 2, mentions: 1 });
  });
});
```

Dose anyone have any suggestion of haw to make my code work?

Comment: let hashTagCount = "So excited to start  @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp".split("#").length - 1;
, Can you check with this one

Comment: like wise you can check the mentionCount also.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. You aren't even attempting to create the expected object. If not familiar with how to use  console logging, now would be a good time to learn. Lots of resources and tutorials around to learn basic debugging approaches

Comment: Editing does not delete questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop does it. Since you're using ES2015+ syntax, a `for-of` would work nicely:

```js
function countHashtagsAndMentions(str) {
  let hashtags = 0;
  let mentions = 0;
  for (const ch of str) {
    if (ch === "#") {
      ++hashtags;
    } else if (ch === "@") {
      ++mentions;
    }
  }
  return {hashtags, mentions};
}
let str = "So excited to start  @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp";
console.log(countHashtagsAndMentions(str));
```

That works because strings are [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) in ES2015+. The [`for-of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) implicitly uses the iterator from the string to walk through its characters. So within the loop, `ch` is each character from the string. Note that unlike `str.split()`, a strings iterator doens't separately the two halves of a character that requires a surrogate pair (like most emojis), which is normally what you want.

This:

```
for (const ch of str) {
    // ...
}
```

is effectively the same as

```
let it = str[Symbol.iterator]();
let rec;
while (!(rec = it.next()).done) {
    const ch = rec.value;
    // ...
}
```

but without the `it` and `rec` variables.

---

Alternately, you could use `replace` with a regular expression to replace all characters other than the ones you want to count. It sounds like it would be more expensive, but it's something the JavaScript engine can optimize:

```js
function countHashtagsAndMentions(str) {
  return {
    hashtags: str.replace(/[^#]/g, "").length,
    mentions: str.replace(/[^@]/g, "").length
  };
}
let str = "So excited to start  @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp";
console.log(countHashtagsAndMentions(str));
```

Which you use probably depends in part on the length of the string. The `replace` option is nice and short, but does go through the string twice.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I have a question about the `for (const ch of str)`. Could you explain how this works I've never used a for loop like that.

Comment: @GeorgiaLumley - I've updated that part of the answer a bit, with some links for further reading. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for checking and counting.

```js
function countHashtagsAndMentions(str) {
    var result = { '#': 0, '@': 0 },
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] in result) ++result[str[i]];
    }
    return result;
}

var str = "So excited to start  @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp";

console.log(countHashtagsAndMentions(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array#reduce

```js
const message = "So excited to start @coding on Monday! #learntocode #codingbootcamp"

const res = message.split("").reduce((acc,cur)=>{
  
  if('#@'.includes(cur)){
    const key = cur === '#' ? 'hashtags' : 'mentions';
    acc[key] = acc[key] + 1;

  }
  
  return acc;
}, {mentions: 0, hashtags: 0})

console.log(res);
```